# App is crashing in production but not in development expo eas build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have created a app using `eas build`. I uploaded the aab to play console because in development, it is working fine, I found no error. I tried using `expo start --minify --no-dev`. Still app is works fine and no error. When I install app from playStore and open my app, it crash. I tried in many other phones but it crash all time after showing splash screen.
my app on [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groluck.quiz).
Is there any solution ?

Comment: Hello. We're you able to find the solution?? I equally have the same error